# Extraer partes especificas de un String

Tags: java, string

Tengo un String llamado "frase" que va a contener cantidades de un producto y quiero extraer lo siguiente:

1. Número antes de palabra "kilos"
2. Número antes de palabra "gramos"
3. Palabra después de palabra "de"

Por ejemplo:
`frase = "2 kilos 350 gramos de Huevo"`

Quiero obtener 3 string con lo siguiente:

```
String kilos = "2";
String gramos = "350";
String producto = "Huevo";
```

Se que con `contains` puedo verificar si contiene las palabras (kilos, gramos, producto) pero como obtengo el texto o numero posterior o anterior a dichas palabras?

**EDICIÓN**

El String no siempre tiene la misma estructura, es decir puede no haber producto o puede no haber kilos, o incluso pueden haber palabras adicionales, un ejemplo:

```
frase = "calcular precio 200 gramos de aguacate"
```

En este caso la salida es:

```
kilos = "";
gramos = "200";
producto= "aguacate";
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? sube tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Hola, en realidad no tengo idea de que puedo hacer, el usuario ingresa por comando de voz el String, y de ahí quiero extraer el número antes de kilo, gramo y la palabra después de "de", se que con `contains` puedo ver si el String contiene la palabra pero no se como ubicarla y tomar el número anterior

Comment: Hola, haz realizado varias preguntas que no han sido bien recibidas en el sitio, es muy importante leer [ask] , saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer eso con una expresión regular:

```
final Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) kilos (\\d+) gramos de (\\w+)");
final String phrase = "2 kilos 350 gramos de Huevo";
final Matcher matcher = rx.matcher(phrase);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Kilos   : " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Gramos  : " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Producto: " + matcher.group(3));
}
```

Produce:

```
Kilos   : 2
Gramos  : 350
Producto: Huevo
```

Comment: Me gusta tu respuesta, la he probado y es útil pero necesito una cosa más, olvidé mencionar que el String puede contener más palabras, intenté hacer esto (para obtener únicamente 2) `Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) kilos");` pero no me muestra nada como salida, noté que con tu código debe de ser exactamente la misma estructura ni mas ni menos y necesito que sin importar la cantidad de palabras que contenga el String extraer solamente lo que está antes de "kilos"

Answer (score -1):

Te doy otra manera de hacerlo que para mi gusto no es nada elegante pero quizas te pueda ayudar en que encuentres lo que en relidad necesitas.

```
final String phrase = "2 kilos 350 gramos de Huevo";

String kilos = "";
String gramos = "";
String producto = "";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\S+(\\s\\S+)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher(phrase);

while (m.find()){
  if(m.group().toLowerCase().contains("kilos")) {
    kilos =  m.group().split(" ")[0];
  }else if (m.group().toLowerCase().contains("gramos")){
    gramos =  m.group().split(" ")[0];
  }else if(m.group().toLowerCase().contains("de")){
    producto = m.group().split(" ")[1];
  }
}

System.out.println("Kilos   : " + kilos);
System.out.println("Gramos  : " + gramos);
System.out.println("Producto: " + producto);
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], una explicación de tu código editando tu aporte haría que calidad mejore notablemente

Comment: El usuario desea ingresar el texto por comando de voz, esto como se realizaría?, es importante lo que comenta @BetaM, hay que responder preguntas que sean realizadas de acuerdo a [ask], saludos.

Comment: Disculpa pero en la pregunta jamas se mensiona en como se realizaria dicha función que mencionas @jorgesys, y tampoco creo que sea justo motivo para votar negativas las respuestas de la comunidad.

Comment: De hecho no realice votación negativa. La pregunta no está creada en base a [ask], si revisas los comentarios el OP indica que quiere realizarlo de está forma, por eso hay que ayudar a estos usuarios a qué formulen correctamente sus preguntas en indiquen que han realizado o investigado.

Comment: Primero que nada muchas gracias por responder, y también a @Jorgesys gracias por la recomendación he leido [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), pero me parece completamente irrelevante mencionar que el texto se ingresa por comando de voz puesto que eso ya lo he conseguido, por eso partí de que tengo un String del cual quiero obtener 3 datos